# Calling concat on proxied array throws error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm new to the ES6 `Proxy` object, and am encountering an error I don't understand when attempting to call `concat` on an array that has been proxied.

Background:

I thought the ES6 `Proxy` would work perfectly as a way to verify the "purity" of a reducer function in my React/Redux application. I can wrap my state object in a proxy that throws an error if I ever attempt to mutate that object. I'm using something based on the [on-change](https://github.com/sindresorhus/on-change) library to do this:

```
const triggersOnChange = (object, onChange) => {
  const handler = {
    get (target, property, receiver) {
      try {
        return new Proxy(target[property], handler)
      } catch (err) {
        return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
      }
    }

    defineProperty (target, property, descriptor) {
      onChange()
      return Reflect.defineProperty(target, property, descriptor)
    }

    deleteProperty (target, property) {
      onChange()
      return Reflect.deleteProperty(target, property)
    }
  }

  return new Proxy(object, handler)
}
```

And here's an example test of how I intend to use the proxy wrapper:

```
describe('reducer', () => {
  test('it returns an updated state object', () => {
    const state = triggersOnChange({ items: [] }, () => {
      throw new Error('Oops! You mutated the state object')
    })

    const action = {
      payload: { item: 'foobar' }
    }

    expect(reducer(state, action)).toEqual({
      items: [action.payload.item]
    })
  })
})
```

If I implement a "bad" reducer that mutates the state object, my test throws an error as intended:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  state.items.push(action.payload.item) // bad
  return state
}

// test throws error "Oops! You mutated the state object"
```

But when I "purify" my reducer by returning a new state object, I get a different error that I don't quite understand:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    items: state.items.concat(action.payload.item)
  })
}

/* 
  TypeError: 'get' on proxy: property 'prototype' is a read-only and
  non-configurable data property on the proxy target but the proxy did
  not return its actual value (expected '[object Array]' but got
  '[object Object]')
      at Proxy.concat (<anonymous>)
*/
```

Am I missing something about proxy behavior here? Or is this perhaps an issue with the proxy-chaining behavior that results from my `get` trap? I initially thought this was a problem with using a proxy within `Object.assign`, but I encountered the same error when debugging before my reducer's return statement, where I actually use `Object.assign`. Help!

Edit: Happy to revise this question to make it a little more generic, but I’m not 100% what the issue is so I’ll wait and see if I can get any answers.

Comment: Not sure if it is your cause, but shouldn't `return new Proxy(target[property], handler)` at least be `return new Proxy(Reflect.get(target, property, receiver), handler)`

Comment: @loganfsmyth I lifted this from the library I linked to ... I think you're right at least stylistically, considering the use of `Reflect` in the catch block. But this didn't have any effect on my results unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem can be replicated with the following code:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", { 
  configurable: false,
  value: {},
});

var p = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    return new Proxy(Reflect.get(target, property, receiver), {});
  },
});

var val = p.prop;
```

The core of the issue is that objects have invariants that they must stay consistent with, even when accessed via a Proxy object, and in this case you are breaking one of those invariants. If you look at [the specification for Proxy's `get`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-get-p-receiver), it states:

> [[Get]] for proxy objects enforces the following invariants:
>
> - The value reported for a property must be the same as the value of the corresponding target object property if the target object property is a non-writable, non-configurable own data property.
> - The value reported for a property must be undefined if the corresponding target object property is a non-configurable own accessor property that has undefined as its [[Get]] attribute.

and in your case, you are not maintaining that first invariant, because even when a property is non-writable and non-configurable, you are returning a wrapping Proxy. The easiest approach would be to ensure that the proper value is returned in that case.

While we're at it, I'll also recommend using `typeof` explicitly instead of using `try`/`catch` so it is clearer.

```
get(target, property, receiver) {
  const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property);
  const value = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);

  if (desc && !desc.writable && !desc.configurable) return value;

  if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) return new Proxy(value, handler);
  else return value;
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to make sure I'm clear, can you verify my interpretation? When calling `Array.prototype.concat`, I'll eventually hit the `get` trap looking up the `prototype` property. But because I'm wrapping in a `Proxy`, the given prototype is not the same as the target object's prototype and therefore breaks rule #1?

Comment: Yeah I didn't dig into the exact path, but some operation you are performing ends up wrapping a non-configurable/non-writable property value, which in this case looks like a `.prototype` property.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the property type is a "function". Even though the second invariant holds, you won't be able to correctly intercept the corresponding call. 
For more details look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977354/illegal-invocation-during-non-configurable-method-call-with-javascript-proxies

Comment: Fun fact: not only is the explicit type check clearer than attempting to create the Proxy and catching the exception, it is also much faster. I did some light benchmarking and the type check is as much as 40x faster than catching the exception. This isn't shocking: exceptions are pretty expensive...