# Force Javascript function invocations to call the Function.prototype.call method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a way to force all javascript function invocations to call the `Function.prototype.call` or the `Function.prototype.apply`.
I plan to have a custom shim around these methods, and want every function invocation to call either one of these methods implicitly.

```
Function.prototype.call = function(thisArg){ 
    console.log("this is my custom call method"); 
} 
a = function(){} 
a(); // Doesn't call my shim
```

Comment: Are you able to monkey patch them before **anything** else might be able to call them?

Comment: Yes, I am able to insert my custom definitions of `Function.prototype.call` and `Functions.prototype.apply` at the start of the script. I want all future function invocations to go through either one of these methods.

Comment: that is only possible for a known set of functions, such as object methods, not for all functions.

Comment: Then they should be.  You have replaced the `call`/`apply` functions and all proceeding calls, when asking for `call`/`apply` will be pointed to your monkey patched functions.  Is this not working?  Can you show code that demonstrates this not working?

Comment: @zero298 he wants to inject code into every function call.

Comment: `call` and `apply` are not called when a function is called, but exists to call a given function with e.g. another context, or to pass arguments programmatically. You there is no way to make all function calls to be wrapped.

Comment: @JonasWilms can you elaborate on how I can automatically invoke the above shim on object methods?

Comment: "*I plan to have a custom shim around these methods*" - what would that custom wrapper do? I'm certain there's a better way to solve your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to intercept function calls is to [Proxy them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply)

```
  function a() { /*...*/ }

  a = new Proxy(a, {
    apply(fn, context, args) {
      console.log("custom things");
      return Reflect.apply(fn, context, args);
    }
 });

 a();
```

However all functions have to be proxied explicitly before the trap gets executed. Or if the function doesnt have properties it is way simpler with:

```
 function wrap(fn) {
   return function(...args) {
     fn.call(this, ...args);
   };
 }

 a = wrap(a);
```

Comment: Well the caveat with this solution is that you need to set the correct context before calling the method. The above handler would give an illegal invocation error for certain functions depending on whether they require a specific `this` value or not.

Comment: @ayush no, the traps are completely invisible, they behave exactly as the original function

Comment: @AyushGoel No, it would not, the `this` value is passed as the `context` to the `apply` handler?

Comment: (Nitpick: it's not the *only* way to intercept them, you could easily write a normal function wrapper. The advantage of the Proxy is just that it also proxies property accesses etc, which may or may not be important).

Comment: I don't mean to digress from the original question but I was using this exact approach until I ran into this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977354/illegal-invocation-during-non-configurable-method-call-with-javascript-proxies
I would sincerely appreciate if you could drop a comment there as well on how to handle that specific case
@Bergi